Intellij infrequently adding newline character in between lines of a text file
I'm having a weird issue where intellij will add a newline character after every line when I'm writing a list of strings to a text file. The doesn't occur every time and in fact when I run the debugger and look at what is being written to my text file I'm seeing no newline character within the string. Sometimes the write command will write to the text file correctly and other times it will not. The output being written is the same and I'm starting to think it's an issue with intellij because when I open the text file in explorer the text file never has those added newlines. Has anyone encountered this issue before and if so what was the fix?
with open(expected_output_path, 'w',  encoding='utf-8') as output:
   for string in actual_output:
      output.write(f"{string}\n")

Here is my code. Assume expected_output_path is the path to the text file, and actual_output is a list[str]

You have \n in the string, that's a newline.

Are you saying that the file is double-spaced when you view it in in the IDE?

Show actual examples of the list of strings that produce the problem. Are there new lines in the strings themselves?

I need the newline there so everything isn't on the same line. There aren't newlines in the strings. It is double spaced when viewed in the IDE but the double spaces don't occur in notepad
